# how to go about with this Short circuit evaluation?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add PictureAlbums along with iframe. Basically, I'm trying to write like this: if timerStates is complete then render  `<iframe>` and also PictureAlbum component.

With the code below I'm able to render only `<PictureAlbums />` and not iframe. How do I solve this?

```
import React from 'react';
import PictureAlbums from './PictureAlbums';
import * as timerStates from './TimerState';


const lp = (val) => {
  if (val < 10) return `0${val}`;
  return `${val}`;
}

const TimerDisplay = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      {
        (props.timerState === timerStates.COMPLETE)
         && <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/"></iframe> 
         && <PictureAlbums />
      }
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>{`${lp(props.currentTime.get('hours'))}:${lp(props.currentTime.get('minutes'))}:${lp(props.currentTime.get('seconds'))}`}</h2>
    </div>
 </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for that to give both elements a common parent without inserting an extra element in the DOM.

```
{props.timerState === timerStates.COMPLETE && (
  <React.Fragment>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/"></iframe> 
    <PictureAlbums />
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```